# Why do you no longer need to use a deduction guide to create a lambda overload set in C++20?

Tags: c++, c++20, template-argument-deduction, ctad

In [Timur Doumler's talk at CppCon 2022, "C++ Lambda Idioms",](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xBAduq0RGes&ab_channel=CppCon) at around 45:19 he is discussing the lambda overload trick and says something like

> In C++17, we had to write a deduction guide to make this work -- which
> is like two more lines of code -- but since C++20 we have [I don't
> know what he is saying] so we don't have to do that any more ...

Why is a deduction guide no longer required to create a lambda overload set in C++20?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the following class template:

```
template<class... Ts> 
struct S : Ts... { };
```

If we want the following initialization to work in C++17:

```
S s{
  [](int) { },
  [](double) { }
};
```

We have to manually add a deduction guide for it since the compiler cannot deduce the type of `Ts...`

```
template<class... Ts>
S(Ts...) -> S<Ts...>;
```

Thanks to the introduction of [P1816 (Class Template Argument Deduction for aggregates)](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1816r0.pdf), we no longer need to explicitly provide a deduction guide for the aggregates type `S` in C++20, the compiler will automatically deduce the type of `Ts...` for us, which is the type of those lambdas.

That's what the video is about

> "but since C++20 we have CTAD (Class template argument deduction) for aggregates..."